# How to apply a Hive schema to unstructured text?

Tags: parsing, hadoop, hive

I have a space delimited text file representing some logs data. For simplicity, headers would be:
'date', 'time',’query’,’host’

And a record would look like:

```
2001-01-01 01:02:04 irfjrifjWt.f=32&ydeyf myhost
```

A simple Hive table with space delimited fields will read this data correctly. However I want to do further parsing of the query string.
Within this text are tags that I want to parse into Hive columns.
Here’s a de-identified example of a couple of query strings:

```
ofifnmfiWT.s=12&ifmrinfnWT.df=hello’&oirjfirngirngWT.gh=32&iurenfur
ggfWT.gh=12&WT.ll=12&uyfer3d
```

Tags have the format WT.xx, followed by an =, followed by the value of the tag, followed by an &.
The order of the tags and the presence of each tag varies from record to record. The only thing I could define ahead is a set of tags I want to parse. In the example above, let’s say I’m interested in tags [WT.gh, WT.s]. Then (making up date time and host), my Hive table would look like:

```
Date                 time         host            WT.s     WT.gh
2011-01-01           05:03:03     myhost1         12       32
2011-01-01           05:03:03     myhost1         NULL     12
```

I could easily parse the query string with Python and regex, and just create a second .txt file with the original record, plus a series of new values with the parsed tags, but that seems a waste of time and it doesn’t look like it is utilizing schema on read principles.
I might be wrong in my thinking, since I’m new to this, but I was wondering if there is a way to apply a schema on this data that would inherently do the parsing for me.
If not, what solution would you recommend?

Comment: See if this link helps you

Comment: You can use what is called a SerDe in Hive and apply a regex to extract your needed fields

Comment: ravindra, which link?

Comment: cricket_007, I thought SerDe are intended to be used when the sequence of data elements is always the same. In the case I described fields are not necessarily in the same order, and sometimes are not even present.